# How to undo git update-index?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-index

I just did the following to to keep a different copy of my config.php file in my localhost vs. my production environment:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged application/config/config.php
```

Unfortunately, I didn't write the config.php file exactly as I should and I need to reverse this such that I can make the change, commit it, and then re-ignore the file.

How do I undo the `git update-index` command?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged application/config/config.php
```

Notice the `--no` prefix, stylistically a double negation.

Comment: thanks that did it! after which I can go back to using `--assume-unchanged`

Comment: How do I do it recursive?

Comment: Same logic applies to `--skip-worktree`, so use `--no-skip-worktree`